# JHipster, Customization of generated code

Tags: jhipster

i'm newbie in JHipster and i'm trying to figure this, when i create a new entity JHipster generates several files, angular, html and java classes, now if  i want a common code for all this generated code i must edit each time that i use the yeoman generator? what i want is:

- Custom Index template, and pages, is secure to edit them?.
- Customize the entity tables, entity forms using angular, maybe extending yeoman generators
- Customize generate java classes, maybe i think using AOP

So i need to edit each time for each generated code? and is a good practice this or what i want? for clarify more i want to use a Custom Bootstrap/angular Dashboard template like [Minovate](http://themeforest.net/item/minovate-angular-admin-dashboard/10068009), i see how to customize bootstrap in the documentation but not about what i'm asking for, Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

JHipster is just a code generator, once generated the code is yours.

For angular screens I would say do as much as you can in CSS/SASS.
But it's very likely that you will need to build some screen mixing several entities and change the structure of entity screens.

So you should rather consider them as a starting point and do your own stuff in another folder so that it does not get overwritten by next re-generations.
This way you can still update your entity definitions in `.jhipster` folder and re-run `yo jhispter:entity <entity name>` on the entities you modified.

Customising java Entities is usually much simpler and you can easiliy achieve this by merging generated code with git and defining your service classes.

AOP seems overkill here.

Extending a yeoman generator is a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks, then if i edit an entity template (for example add a button) or code and for some reasons i need to add a new property is better to edit it manually that run the yeoman routine and lost my work? or you mean use the yeoman generator and copy that code in another folder for edit?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use some VSC (git, subversion or whatever you like) have a branch dedicated to plain jhipster generated code and another one where you make customization.
Eventually regenerate on jhipster branch and merge back on yours.

You should at least reduce manual intervention.